# this.Control doesn't work

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

```
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WpfTestApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string myName;
            myName = "textBox1";
            this.Controls.Find(myName);
        }
    }
}
```

The above code returns the following error:

> Error  1   'WpfTestApp.MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'Controls' and no extension method 'Controls' accepting a first argument of type 'WpfTestApp.MainWindow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

`this.` doesn't offer `Controls` as an option through intellisense. But I've seen `this.Contols.find(<name of control>)` in code examples before. But I can't seem to get it to work.

Any help would be appreciated, I'm using c# with Visual Studio 2010

Comment: ups, sorry wrong message

Comment: You should accept one of the answers. The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) recommends that you accept the answer that is "the most helpful to you".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you've seen before is for [Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find%28VS.80%29.aspx) and you're trying to work with WPF. You might want to *try*:

```
this.FindName(myName);
```

This is the [`FrameworkElement.FindName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname.aspx) method and will find something that has an `x:Name` associatd with it.

Answer (score 3):

`Controls` is a WinForms property, but you are using WPF.

It's all completely different in WPF. For example, the `Window` class does not support children which is why there is no `Controls` property.

Without knowing what you are trying to achieve it's hard to recommend the right solution.

Comment: That could explain a lot, which is why i've been getting very frustrated.  I literally have no hair left.  Doh!

Comment: @FrustratedNewbie - I do feel that Microsofts choice of `System.Windows.Forms` for WinForms and `System.Windows` for WPF was possibly **one of the stupidest mistakes they've ever made, including Comic Sans**. =)

Comment: Basically i have say 20 textboxes all named sequentially (textbox1, textbox2, textbox3 etc) and i run these through a loop, something like  for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)   which will test if a condition is true or not, and if it is then i want to edit that textbox along the lines of  myName = "textBox" + i.ToString();
this.Control(myName).Text = “YES”
Thats roughly what i was trying to achieve.

Comment: @FrustratedNewbie try `this.FindName()`

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
this.FindName(myName);
```

This will work if you have assigned an `x:name` to your control.

Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/wpf-ways-to-find-controls) as this is a more robust solution.